# Only one commit message to all files in github

Tags: git, github

How can i give only one commit message to all files in git
eg: if i commit two files say `sample.txt` and `sample1.txt` commit message is shows like this

I this it will shows the same commit message (ie added new text files) for two files ,instead of that I want to show the same commit message for two files commonly.

So how can I do that?

[image]

Comment: That's the same commit message.

Comment: That's just how GitHub displays it - for each file, it shows you the start of the most recent commit message for that file. There is actually only one commit which contains changes to multiple files, and that commit has a message.

Comment: Add all changed files before you commit. You can also do `git commit -am "Message" ` to add and commit all tracked files.

Comment: @Maroun i want to change the display style not the commit message

Comment: @BlessanKurien You can't. Every commited file must have a message.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking a question very special to Github's (at least I assume its github as it looks like) user interface. The interface is showing per default the last commit message of the commit done on this folder/file. This can be translated like: "the file has been changes last time with this message". If you change multiple files, multiple files will have the same message.

But: As you can see at the meaning it doesn't make big sense to have all files showing the same message per default. 
However, if you can change the default behavior here needs to be checked with github's support team.